# How to get Zxing in python working with Heroku?

Tags: java, python, flask, heroku, zxing

I am deploying a python flask app to heroku which uses Zxing to read qr codes(scan them) and give out the data on them, however Zxing requires Java on the heroku environment.

Zxing : https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing

**Error with Zxing**

```
barcode = reader.decode(f) #qrreader.data#
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zxing/__init__.py", line 48, in decode
raise BarCodeReaderException("Java binary specified does not exist", self.java, e)
zxing.BarCodeReaderException: ('Java binary specified does not exist', 'java', FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: 'java'"))
```

**What I have Tried**

Added the java buildpack to the environment along side python but that spits out an error and i am not sure if it would solve the problem either way.

the Java buildpack from heroku

```
heroku/java
```

Looked for other libraries that can do the same job with only python(found none)(zbar dependency issues)

**My current build packs**

```
https://github.com/survantjames/heroku-buildpack-poppler.git
heroku/python
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
```

All of this works on a local windows 10 environment with java installed and no other changes.

**Is there a way to get Zxing working or is there an alternative that will work?**

Thanks:D

***EDIT:***
Java Build error details.(irrelevant, check below answer)

```
Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> JVM Common app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Using provided JDK
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
remote: -----> Executing Maven
remote:        $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
remote:        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
remote:        [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
remote:        [ERROR] 'modelVersion' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [FATAL] 'groupId' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [FATAL] 'artifactId' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [FATAL] 'version' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:         @
remote:        [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR]   The project [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version] (/tmp/build_7e2d7b50/pom.xml) has 4 errors
remote:        [ERROR]     'modelVersion' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [ERROR]     'groupId' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [ERROR]     'artifactId' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [ERROR]     'version' is missing. @ line 1, column 9
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to invoice-parser.
```

Comment: "but that spits out an error"—well, what does that error _say?_ Please read [ask].

Comment: Really sorry for the confusion but i did not add the java error in the question as i felt it was a build error which was irrelevent since that java buildpack even if it built out wouldnt solve my problem as was the case. Will keep in mind[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for the future.

Comment: "since that java buildpack even if it built out wouldnt solve my problem"—why do you say this?

Comment: cause that will make my app heavier also what i need is not the java development files but rather only jvm

Comment: Right, but you didn't provide error messages or clearly say what buildpack you were using. The errors would have made clear what the problem was. Anyway, glad you got this figured out.

Comment: Ya sorry for that, i have added all the things that are missing:(, its my second question here sorry

Comment: Thanks for updating. Things are much clearer now. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve my error by adding the buildpack

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common.git
```

in place of the java buildpack( ***EDIT:*** heroku/java) heroku provides, the buildpack i have used just installs jvm to my environment ***EDIT:*** which is also provided by heroku and is mentioned in [link](https://help.heroku.com/2FSHO0RR/how-can-i-add-java-to-a-non-java-app).

Zxing now builds fine :D

***EDIT:*** There was confusion due to bad writing on my part but i do not at all mean that heroku does not provide these buildpacks. Me saying "in place" here shoud be taken in context of the question and as such it is in place of the original buildpack(heroku/java). It in no place or form means that heroku does not provide the buildpacks.

Thanks for pointing out the confusion

Comment: That's not "in place of the java buildpack heroku provides" since Heroku _provides that buildpack_. Just look at its URL: it's in the Heroku namespace on GitHub. And it is [listed as an official buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common) on Heroku's elements site. In the future, please e as specific as possible when asking your question. Tell us the _specific_ buildpack you are trying to use and the exact error message you see.

Comment: Ok ive added the changes to the question, thanks for guiding me:D

Comment: Also im not saying anywhere that the buildpacks provided are not from heroku. i have just said that "in place" since the buildpack heroku/java can be added from the UI itself in the buildpack section and the one i have used is mentioned in the documentation but not on the main UI page. I am fairly new to heroku so am not sure if there are other ways people handle buildpacks, so sorry for the confusion